# Image in table not placed as expected?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two images side by side in a table and have the following behavior on the first image:

1. Have it be right up against the bottom of the table, so the bottom border is overlapping with the bottom border of the table.
2. Have no right margin or padding, so it is right against the second image (so the right border of the first image is overlapping with the left border of the second image).

To solve the first thing I'm using `valign="bottom"` but that doesn't seem to fully work.

To solve the second issue I'm using `padding-right:0px; margin-right:0px;` but that doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me achieve the behavior I'm going for please? Note that I'm using a table because I have other things in this table, I just took them out to simplify the question.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.benderImg {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.benderImg > img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table width="666" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="benderImg" valign="bottom">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_WR2Eqmcd2zXlhYpDN1oMRmystiCn-ECZfLgM5JuJg58Enn7V"></img>
    <td>
    <td valign="bottom">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRctutHJ3tMB4vgZ9bEwX8VACeXgAvbGX09iUht_h8Ci3-OSAtBqg"></img>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using obsolete attributes, which is not recommended. Besides, some of the attributes try to set different values than the properties in the CSS, which is a no-no. Replace them all with CSS properties.

Secondly, the vertical align property should be on the img rather than on the td.

Then the distance between the two images; the second image has no border or margin, and neither does its td, so I'm not sure why you think there should be some spacing in between. I put a left padding on the td; you can change that to fit your needs.

And finally, `</img>` is unnecessary; not allowed even, since `<img>` is a void element. You can end the `<img`> tag with a slash if you want.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 666px;     /* css replacement for width attr */
  border-spacing:0; /* css replacement for cellspacing attr */
}

td {
  padding:0;        /* css replacement for cellpadding attr */
}

.benderImg {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.benderImg > img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

.benderImg + td {
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="benderImg">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_WR2Eqmcd2zXlhYpDN1oMRmystiCn-ECZfLgM5JuJg58Enn7V" alt="" />
    <td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRctutHJ3tMB4vgZ9bEwX8VACeXgAvbGX09iUht_h8Ci3-OSAtBqg" alt="">
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see two tricks that should work for you. In first I've made `td` to be `display: flex` with two alignments. ;). In second I used inside `div` element with flex, so to not change default `display: table-cell` for `td` element. I've also fixed typos in tags you used.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.benderImg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.benderImg>img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table width="666" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="benderImg">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_WR2Eqmcd2zXlhYpDN1oMRmystiCn-ECZfLgM5JuJg58Enn7V" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRctutHJ3tMB4vgZ9bEwX8VACeXgAvbGX09iUht_h8Ci3-OSAtBqg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.benderImg {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.benderImg>div>img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.benderImg > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table width="666" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="benderImg">
    <div>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_WR2Eqmcd2zXlhYpDN1oMRmystiCn-ECZfLgM5JuJg58Enn7V" />
    </div>
      <td>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRctutHJ3tMB4vgZ9bEwX8VACeXgAvbGX09iUht_h8Ci3-OSAtBqg" />
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second issue, I fixed it by just using `align="right"` on the first image's td. The first issue was fixed with a `vertical-align: bottom` on the first image.